# Some keys aren't working on my laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I got an asus zenbook prime a few months ago and some of the keys aren't working anymore. Specifically I can't use the ~, 1, 2, -, backspace, q, e, a, z, or x keys. I don't use it that much so it seems unlikely that the cause is dirt. Please help.

Comment: If you know what you are doing you should open it up and make sure the cable from the board to the keyboard is in snug.

Comment: I definitely don't know what I'm doing in that respect.

Comment: If you google for '<your laptop model> disassembly instructions', there are guides for taking machines apart, with pictures. You'd only need to get to the part with 'remove keyboard', then instead of detaching the cable check it's firmly attached. Then undo steps to put it back together.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a hardware issue. Take it to a computer hardware repair shop.

You could try using a key mapper to map the unusable to keys to other keys that you do not use often.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.softpedia.com/hubs/Key-Mapper) for a key mapper that suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

multipin connector has come loose.

http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Unresponsive+Keyboard+Keys/11932/1

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.